# pass a variable to prototype Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send the selector value to the prototype. Currently i am using

```
var selector; //id of html element
function $(selector)
{
    if(window===this)
        return new $(selector);
    return this;
}
$.prototype={
    tooltip: function(){
        console.log(selector);
        //do calculations with the selector value
        return this;
    }
};
```

It is showing undefined.

Is there any way to pass variable?

Comment: And where are you calling `.tooltip`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot access it from the prototype methods. The `selector` parameter is a local variable to the constructor.

However, you can make it available as a property on your instance:

```
function $(selector) {
    if(!(this instanceof $))
        return new $(selector);

    this.selector = selector; // assigns the variable to a property
}
$.prototype.tooltip = function(){
    console.log(this.selector); // access the property on the instance
    //do calculations with the selector value
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are calling any of your functions or setting `selector`. However, one problem is that the formal function parameter `selector` in your definition of `$` masks the outer variable also named `selector`. If you eliminate the function parameter, it should work better (assuming that you are also somewhere setting `selector`):

```
var selector; //id of html element
function $()
{
    if(window===this)
        return new $(selector);
    return this;
}
$.prototype={
    tooltip: function(){
        console.log(selector);
        //do calculations with the selector value
        return this;
    }
};
```

The way your code is written now, it is as if it were written as follows:

```
var selector; //id of html element
function $(x)
{
    if(window===this)
        return new $(x);
    return this;
}
$.prototype={
    tooltip: function(){
        console.log(selector);
        //do calculations with the selector value
        return this;
    }
};
```

Comment: No, eliminating the constructor function parameter will definitely not help the prototype method…

Comment: @Bergi - It depends on what OP expects the constructor to be. If inside the constructor OP wants to access the global variable `selector`, then it definitely will help.